# How can I best edit out window reflection in this photo?

Tags: editing

I took this photo in Vancouver a while ago and would like to make a poster out of it.

Unfortunately, I didn't have the necessary equipment to avoid window reflection.

It's been edited in Lightroom but you can see lighter zones at the top and top right.

There also seem to be lines at the bottom right.

I've tried using a brush but not satisfied with the result.

What do you suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop's healing brush will have a fair go at it.

[image]

This was literally one brush stroke across the entire 3-stripe section - it's not perfect, it's messed up the buildings a bit [though it might be hard to spot without the comparison pic] but with a bit of care & attention on the full-size original, I'm sure it will do well.

It made a reasonable job of the light/dark barring in the top half too, but it's harder to see at these sizes.

Comment: Healing brush: Not just for dust and zits.

Comment: @Hueco - LOL, yup. Actually Pshop's healing brush has come on in leaps & bounds over the past few years. I'm guessing it's now using the same type of AI that the Content-aware Fills are using.

Comment: That's a great result. Does it have an advantage over Lightroom's brush?

Comment: I don't use Lr, so I can't say, sorry. I would imagine they are similar, if you're on a recent version. That brush has improved a lot over the years, so if you're still on CS6 or so, then it won't be as good.

Comment: @JamesP. Different uses. I use the Lightroom brush for dust and some light retouching. For something more major like this, I'd prefer to use PS for the additional features built into the tool (blend modes, diffusion) and layers support. Lightroom is good, but not much beats PS + Wacom for major editing.

Comment: It really has come a long way Tetsujin. I remember when you needed to clone stamp or copy/paste sections over other sections in order to heal/blend them together because the healing brush pulled too many colors into the diffusion zone when dealing with high contrast and hard lines. Only thing I hate about Adobe now is the monthly fee >_<.